# Execute RFT script on a button click from VB.NET

Tags: rft

I have automation scripts in RFT. I have designed UI in VS2012(coding in aspx.vb) which takes all the input fields here. I need to execute the RFT script on a click of a button taking all the fields from UI as arguments. Any help??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

could you elaborate on the issue more ?

> *need to execute the RFT script on a click of a button*

which button are you referring to ?

EDIT -  I hope it's not too late , What I understand is that from your application (ASP.NET based) , you want to execute an RFT script based on the parameters of the input fields in the application .
For that  depending on the type of RFT scripts you have  (VB scripts or Java Scripts)
you can use one of the following:

```
java -jar <BIN>\rational_ft.jar -datastore <path to the project> -playback <scriptname without extn>
```

or

```
    <BIN>\rational_ft.exe -datastore <path to the project> -playback <scriptname without extn>
```

Both , rational_ft.jar and rational_ft.exe reside in the BIN directory of RFT installation .
(Usually  C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\FunctionalTester\Bin on a 32 bit windows machine).

From your application you would need to be able to start a process and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RFT command line interface](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rfthelp/v8r5/nav/26_4).